# i have a loop that is not working on ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have loop that is checking if there is no image display a dummy image. I don't know what is wrong with this loop. It is not display the dummy image.Any help will be appreciated. Thank you

```
 .col-md-12
  - @applied_users.each do |user|
    .applied 
    %a
      %a.litle-modules.pull-left{href: show_user_public_path(user.id, ((Apply.where user_id: user.id, job_id: @job.id).first).id)}
        .col-xs-6.col-md-5
          .thumbnail
            - if user.image != nil
              = image_tag "profile_pic.jpeg"
            - elsif user.image.nil?
              = image_tag "profile_pic.jpeg"
        .col-md-7.pull-right
          %h2= user.fname
          %p= user.location
          %p= user.description

def show_private
        #this method is responsible for showing the companies their job application page after matches have been made and after people have applied. 
        neo_results_array = []
        percentage_match = []
        @job = Job.find(params[:id])
        @neo_results = Neo4jProcess.match_users(@job.id, 20000)

        filtered_results = JSON.parse(@neo_results)
        users = filtered_results["users"]
        users.each do |user|
            if user["score"] >= 0.005
                neo_results_array << user["user_id"]
                percentage_match << user["score"]
            else
            end
        end
        @final_array = neo_results_array.zip(percentage_match)
        print @final_array

        if @job.applies == [] && neo_results_array == []
            redirect_to share_page_path(@job.id)
        else @job.applies != [] || neo_results_array != []
            applied = @job.applies.pluck(:user_id)
            @applied_users = User.find(applied) 
            percentage_user_array = []

            @final_array.each do |item|
                percentage_user_array << item[0] 
            end
            @matched_users = User.find(percentage_user_array)
      end   
    end
```

just edited. here you can see my controller responsible for the img and other things

Answer (score 0):

Remove condition from else

If you want to put some conditions for else as well use

```
 elsif user.image.nil?
```

Comment: Are you sure user.image is nil?

Comment: Try now. Edited the answer. You dont see any error right?

Comment: no I don't see any errors.What u just edited is not working as well. Do you thing the error could be in the controller?

Comment: Post your controller action and your whole view file. Atleast the loop.

Comment: Try to debug that if its not picking up the image by replacing image tag with some text. We will get to know if it loop issue or image issue

Comment: my understanding is that the if condition is good. the problem is that is not looping to the elsif contion

Comment: That means user.image is never nil. Its always satisfying the first condition for if

Comment: i think i am just going to write a jquery method and not complicate my self. Thank you for your help anyways...